Is there a way to allocate more than 64 bytes of memory in MASM (MS-DOS)
So, i wrote a simple program that prints the contents of a file that is specified in the command-line arguments, and i have a major issue with the memory allocation,
Basically, i dynamically allocate memory using INT 21h, 48h and use the allocated space to store the file's contents, the issue i have with it at the moment is that it doesn't allow me to allocate more than 4 paragraphs of memory, which is 64 bytes, or else it'll throw an error about insufficient memory. And that's quite a small amount of memory.
So, if you can tell me about another way that let me allocate more than 64 bytes, that'd be appreciated!

It should work up to the size of the available memory. Note that also depends on how much memory is allocated via the EXE header.

@Jester i used MEM to show me the amount of available memory, and i can promise you it's way more than 64 bytes.

@Jester by the way, what do you mean by the memory depends on the exe header??

There is a field in the executable file that specifies how much memory to allocate to the program initially. You can only allocate dynamically from the remainder.

And for .com files, the .com file gets all the available memory so there won't be anything left to allocate.

@Jester how can i modify the field then?

Depends on your toolchain. Or you can first free some memory via int21/4a but to only do that so you can allocate it again makes little sense.

@Jester im using MASM-

It depends on your linker not your assembler. For microsoft link it seems to be /CP:number which "Sets the program’s maximum memory allocation to number of 16-byte paragraphs. "

@Jester i set the number of maximum paragraphs to 4096 (for 64kB) and it worked! tysm :D
